# Using reflection principle, where did things go wrong?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

$W(t)$ is a Wiener process.
Denote $M(t)= \min_{0 \leq s \leq t} W(s)$.
I am trying to calculate $P(M(t) \geq -m, W(t) \leq w)$ with $m,w>0$.
Rewriting:
$$
P(M(t) \geq -m, W(t) \leq w)= P(W(t) \leq w) -P(M(t) \leq -m, W(t) \leq w)
$$
Using the reflection principle (this is probably where things go wrong):
$$
P(M(t) \leq -m, W(t) \leq w)= P(W(t) \geq -m -w)= P(W(t) \leq m+w)
$$
And then
$$
P(M(t) \geq -m, W(t) \leq w) = P(W(t) \leq w) -P(W(t) \leq m+w)
$$
which is definitely wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: Since the reflection property uses the Strong Markov Property at the first hitting time of $-m$, you actually have to reflect on the line $y=-m$, not $y=0$. So your middle expression becomes $P[M_t \leq -m, W_t \leq w] = P[M_t \leq -m, W_t \geq -m - (w-(-m))] = P[M_t \leq -m, W_t \geq -2m-w]$.

Comment: and how should I proceed from there? thanks

Comment: I tried your approach, but it ended up with negative probability still